# Concatenate equivalent in MATLAB for a single value

Tags: matlab, variables

I am trying to use MATLAB in order to generate a variable whose elements are either 0 or 1. I want to define this variable using some kind of concatenation (equivalent of Java string append) so that I can add as many 0's and 1's according to some upper limit.

I can only think of using a for loop to append values to an existing variable. Something like

```
variable=1;
for i=1:N
    if ( i%2==0)
        variable = variable.append('0')
    else 
        variable = variable.append('1')
    i=i+1;
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB, you can almost always avoid a loop by treating arrays in a vectorized way.

The result of pseudo-code you provided can be obtained in a single line as:

```
variable = mod((1:N),2);
```

The above line generates a row vector `[1,2,...,N]` (with the code `(1:N)`, use `(1:N)'` if you need a column vector)  and the `mod` function (as most MATLAB functions) is applied to each element when it receives an array.

Answer (score 2):

That's not valid Matlab code:

1. The `%` indicates the start of a comment, hence introducing a syntax error.
2. There is no `append` method (at least not for arrays).
3. Theres no need to increment the index in a for loop.

Aside of that it's a bad idea to have Matlab "grow" variables, as memory needs to be reallocated at each time, slowing it down considerably. The correct approach is:

```
variable=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    variable(i)=mod(i,2);
end
```

If you really do want to grow variables (some times it is inevitable) you can use this:

```
variable=[variable;1];
```

Use `;` for appending rows, use `,` for appending columns (does the same as `vertcat` and `horzcat`). Use `cat` if you have more than 2 dimensions in your array.